# Max number of columns using Table() for SQLAlchemy Core - Python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy Core in Python to build MySQL tables. I use the Table() function as follows:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#define-and-create-tables

As you can see, each column is given as an argument of the function. The problem is that Python functions only handle a maximum of 255 arguments, but I need to build a table with 400 arguments. Is there a way to circumvent the argument limit in Python? Or perhaps another function I can use build the table? I tried submitting the columns/arguments as a list, but this did not work.

Thank you!

Edit:
I am attempting to use the same Table() format as in the SQLAlchemy Core tutorial. For instance:

```
addresses = Table('addresses', metadata,
Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
Column('user_id', None, nullable=False),
Column('email_address', String, nullable=False))
```

This use of the Table() will create three columns, obviously. However I want to create another 397 (different) columns but can't because Table() will only take 255 arguments. Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work just fine?

What's your issue exactly?

**EDIT**

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
metadata = MetaData()
hello =  [Column('x{}'.format(i), String, nullable=False) for i in range(1000)]
t = Table('t', metadata, *hello)
print t.__dict__
print t.__dict__.get("_columns")
#{'schema': None, '_columns': <sqlalchemy.sql.base.ColumnCollection object at 0x026C68A0>, 'name': 't', 'dispatch': <sqlalchemy.event.base.DDLEventsDispatch object at 0x02133B70>, 'indexes': set([]), 'foreign_keys': set([]), 'columns': <sqlalchemy.sql.base.ImmutableColumnCollection object at 0x02717300>, '_prefixes': [], '_extra_dependencies': set([]), 'fullname': 't', 'metadata': MetaData(bind=None), 'implicit_returning': True, 'constraints': set([PrimaryKeyConstraint()]), 'primary_key': PrimaryKeyConstraint()}
#['t.x0', 't.x1', 't.x2', 't.x3', 't.x4', 't.x5', 't.x6', 't.x7', 't.x8', 't.x9', 't.x10', 't.x11', 't.x12', 't.x13', 't.x14', 't.x15', 't.x16', 't.x17', 't.x18', 't.x19', 't.x20', 't.x21', 't.x22', 't.x23', 't.x24', 't.x25', 't.x26', 't.x27', 't.x28', 't.x29', 't.x30', 't.x31', 't.x32', 't.x33', 't.x34', 't.x35', 't.x36', 't.x37', 't.x38', 't.x39', 't.x40', 't.x41', 't.x42', 't.x43', 't.x44', 't.x45', 't.x46', 't.x47', 't.x48', 't.x49', 't.x50', 't.x51', 't.x52', 't.x53', 't.x54', 't.x55', 't.x56', 't.x57', 't.x58', 't.x59', 't.x60', 't.x61', 't.x62', 't.x63', 't.x64', 't.x65', 't.x66', 't.x67', 't.x68', 't.x69', 't.x70', 't.x71', 't.x72', 't.x73', 't.x74', 't.x75', 't.x76', 't.x77', 't.x78', 't.x79', 't.x80', 't.x81', 't.x82', 't.x83', 't.x84', 't.x85', 't.x86', 't.x87', 't.x88', 't.x89', 't.x90', 't.x91', 't.x92', 't.x93', 't.x94', 't.x95', 't.x96', 't.x97', 't.x98', 't.x99', 't.x100', 't.x101', 't.x102', 't.x103', 't.x104', 't.x105', 't.x106', 't.x107', 't.x108', 't.x109', 't.x110', 't.x111', 't.x112', 't.x113', 't.x114', 't.x115', 't.x116', 't.x117', 't.x118', 't.x119', 't.x120', 't.x121', 't.x122', 't.x123', 't.x124', 't.x125', 't.x126', 't.x127', 't.x128', 't.x129', 't.x130', 't.x131', 't.x132', 't.x133', 't.x134', 't.x135', 't.x136', 't.x137', 't.x138', 't.x139', 't.x140', 't.x141', 't.x142', 't.x143', 't.x144', 't.x145', 't.x146', 't.x147', 't.x148', 't.x149', 't.x150', 't.x151', 't.x152', 't.x153', 't.x154', 't.x155', 't.x156', 't.x157', 't.x158', 't.x159', 't.x160', 't.x161', 't.x162', 't.x163', 't.x164', 't.x165', 't.x166', 't.x167', 't.x168', 't.x169', 't.x170', 't.x171', 't.x172', 't.x173', 't.x174', 't.x175', 't.x176', 't.x177', 't.x178', 't.x179', 't.x180', 't.x181', 't.x182', 't.x183', 't.x184', 't.x185', 't.x186', 't.x187', 't.x188', 't.x189', 't.x190', 't.x191', 't.x192', 't.x193', 't.x194', 't.x195', 't.x196', 't.x197', 't.x198', 't.x199', 't.x200', 't.x201', 't.x202', 't.x203', 't.x204', 't.x205', 't.x206', 't.x207', 't.x208', 't.x209', 't.x210', 't.x211', 't.x212', 't.x213', 't.x214', 't.x215', 't.x216', 't.x217', 't.x218', 't.x219', 't.x220', 't.x221', 't.x222', 't.x223', 't.x224', 't.x225', 't.x226', 't.x227', 't.x228', 't.x229', 't.x230', 't.x231', 't.x232', 't.x233', 't.x234', 't.x235', 't.x236', 't.x237', 't.x238', 't.x239', 't.x240', 't.x241', 't.x242', 't.x243', 't.x244', 't.x245', 't.x246', 't.x247', 't.x248', 't.x249', 't.x250', 't.x251', 't.x252', 't.x253', 't.x254', 't.x255', 't.x256', 't.x257', 't.x258', 't.x259', 't.x260', 't.x261', 't.x262', 't.x263', 't.x264', 't.x265', 't.x266', 't.x267', 't.x268', 't.x269', 't.x270', 't.x271', 't.x272', 't.x273', 't.x274', 't.x275', 't.x276', 't.x277', 't.x278', 't.x279', 't.x280', 't.x281', 't.x282', 't.x283', 't.x284', 't.x285', 't.x286', 't.x287', 't.x288', 't.x289', 't.x290', 't.x291', 't.x292', 't.x293', 't.x294', 't.x295', 't.x296', 't.x297', 't.x298', 't.x299'.....]
```

In the example above I'm using a list comprehension to create 1000 columns and pass it into my table function. You will have to define each one, one by one.

Also, it should be noted that a table of 400 columns isn't necessarily a good idea, and you should probably be planning how to effectively create multiple tables rather then one large table.

Comment: I'm basically putting all the columns in the list, and passing the list with an asterisk.

Comment: I don't quite understand your solution. Where are you defining the data types, nullable, etc? Sorry if this is such a basic question, I'm very new to Python. Any chance you can leverage the Table() format I used above?

Comment: I revised using the same exact imports you have.
Basically what you can do is place all the Column() into a list, and assign that list to the Table function.

In the example above I'm using a list comprehension to create 1000 columns and pass it into my table function. You will have to define each one, one by one into the list.

Comment: I think I understand now. I would have to supply separate lists when the arguments change. So for my "String, nullable=False" columns I would the "hello" list, but for my "Integer" columns I would have to supply another list. Is this correct?

Comment: No, you would create the whole list.
`[Column('column1', Integer, Primary.....), Column('column2', String,     nullable=True, ...) ]`

I just used list comprehension to create it quickly in the example. You can just create one very large list by hand.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I noticed you passed the list with an asterisk...why is the asterisk needed?

Comment: An argument will be unpacked and not packed. In other words, the elements of the list or tuple are singularized. Hopefully this works out, and you accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually heading out, but will try your solution later today and accept when it works. Again, thank you!